# Parity of object made up of Dirac spinors and gamma matrices

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, parity

I am reading Introduction to Elementary Particles by Griffiths, specifically the chapter on Dirac equation.

Griffiths states without proof, that the expression $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi$ is a pseudovector. As I understand, this means that it has even parity. I am trying to prove this. Here I go:

$$(\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi)'=(\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi)'$$
(definition of $\bar{\psi}$). Note that I use prime for Parity operator (so does Griffiths).
$$=(\psi^\dagger)'\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^5(\psi)'$$
$$=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\gamma^0\psi$$
(where we used the result quoted by Griffiths: ($(\psi)'=\gamma^0\psi$)
$$=\psi^\dagger\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\gamma^0\psi$$
($(\gamma^0)^2=1$)
$$=-\psi^\dagger\gamma^\mu\gamma^0\gamma^5\psi$$
($\gamma^5 $ and $\gamma^0$ anti-commute). From here, I have to bring the $\gamma^0$ to the left of $\gamma^\mu$. If these two anti-commute, I am through (see below). But in general they do so only if $\mu \neq$0. For the case $\mu=0$, I get the opposite result. What is wrong here?

If $\mu \neq0$, the last expression becomes $(-1)^2\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi=\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\gamma^5\psi$, as should be for it to be a pseudovector.

Comment: A psi has gone in your first equality. Just for clarity. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Correction made!